# Tor for IOT - connecting a microcontroller to internet through Tor - Arduino Tor

Tags: network-configuration

Tor has some really amazing features such as NAT Punching Feature which allows a unique relatively secret .onion URL which can be accessed form anywhere in the world via Tor network. This has tremendous potential in the world of Iot and various Wireless Sensor Network applications.

I would like to know if there is currently any mechanism (perhaps a support package for arduino like MCUs) for a microcontroller and a small ESP8266 WiFi SoC to be a part of the awesome Tor network.

Is there anyone working on this type of work?

Secondly, I would also like to know your opinions about this type of work in case if you happen to answer the question.

Comment: I've done this a lot using the Raspberry Pi. It's easy to set up hidden web servers etc. It would be nice to be able to use Tor from smaller devices such as the ESP8266 though.

Comment: An implementation of Tor for the ESP32 would be amaizing!

Answer (score 2):

I released a Tor implementation based on ESP32.
I have done it for educational purposes and the code is in modern C++ based on IDF framework.
Lack of resources was an hard issue, however it works very well if you do not search for performances. I think this is the first project on Tor/IOT topic :)
Take a look: https://github.com/briand-hub/toresp32

Answer (score 1):

It's hardly possible due to the lack of resources on board: 256 or 512 Mb of RAM is a requirement for running Tor and Linux image.

UPDATE: there're a devices like [PCDuino](http://www.linksprite.com/linksprite-pcduino/) - so they're a perfect choice for Tor and IoT, 100% Arduino compatible, [this one](http://www.linksprite.com/pcduino8-uno/) will be just awesome, I think.

Comment: we could run c code without running linux. we can go bare metal. Im just sayin.

Comment: You really don't need anywhere near that much RAM, e.g. [PORTAL](https://github.com/grugq/portal) says 32MB of RAM is sufficient, but recommends 64MB.

Comment: Cache-less operation is a bad idea in matters of speed and stability. If something is possible physically it doesn't mean that it works

Comment: @Qwertylicious I know, I'm playing with STM and other arm chips myself. Tor will launch kernel less, but it needs a cache memory, and here goes the problem. Either you do a paging, or using a very slow SPI memory

Comment: @canonizingironize even PORTAL states that 16Mb system is "almost unuseable", and - as far as I know - the maximum amount of RAM is 64Mb on [Arduino Yun](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun). But even using PORTAL - keep in mind that it's OpenWRT-based package, so - it *will boot up and run*, the question is how much resources will be left for the device's functionality itself

Comment: 16MB works but is "almost unusable", 32MB works, 64MB is comfortable.

Comment: @canonizingironize  for PORTAL-only setup - yes, but keep in mind that the device's "smart guts" will require some additional resources too. That's the point of concern